# Spring MVC hello world

Tags: spring-mvc, web

First I wanna apologize for maybe duplicate topic but I couldn't find the answer to my question.

I try to start to learn Spring MVC 3.0.

I like Netbeans IDE(using 7.0.1) I find couple of tutorials but as a newbie I am confused because some use annotations and some property XML. I understand the concept of MVC architecture. But don't understand the xml settings.

What I want to achieve is move from index.htm(.jsp?) to HelloWorldPage.htm .

index.jsp

```
<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
        <title>Welcome to Spring Web MVC project</title>
    </head>

    <body>
        <p>Hello! This is the default welcome page for a Spring Web MVC project.</p>
        <a href ="HelloWorldPage.htm">Hello</a>
    </body>
</html>
```

HelloWorldPage.jsp

```
<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
        <title>JSP Page</title>
    </head>
     <body>
    <h1>Hello!</h1>
    </body>
</html>
```

HelloWorldController.java

```
public class HelloWorldController extends AbstractController{   

         @Override
    protected ModelAndView handleRequestInternal(HttpServletRequest request,
        HttpServletResponse response) throws Exception {

        ModelAndView model = new ModelAndView("HelloWorldPage");
        return model;
    }

}
```

Dispatcher-servlet.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
       xmlns:p="http://www.springframework.org/schema/p"
       xmlns:aop="http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop"
       xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
       xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop/spring-aop-3.0.xsd
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx-3.0.xsd">

    <bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.support.ControllerClassNameHandlerMapping"/>


    <!--
    Most controllers will use the ControllerClassNameHandlerMapping above, but
    for the index controller we are using ParameterizableViewController, so we must
    define an explicit mapping for it.
    -->
    <bean id="urlMapping" class="org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.SimpleUrlHandlerMapping">
        <property name="mappings">
            <props>
                <prop key="index.htm">indexController</prop>
            </props>
        </property>
    </bean>

    <bean id="viewResolver"
          class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver"
          p:prefix="/WEB-INF/jsp/"
          p:suffix=".jsp" />

    <!--
    The index controller.
    -->
    <bean name="indexController"
          class="org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.ParameterizableViewController"
          p:viewName="index" />

</beans>
```

web.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app version="3.0" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd">
    <context-param>
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value>/WEB-INF/applicationContext.xml</param-value>
    </context-param>
    <listener>
        <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
    </listener>
    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>dispatcher</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
        <load-on-startup>2</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>dispatcher</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>*.htm</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
    <session-config>
        <session-timeout>
            30
        </session-timeout>
    </session-config>
    <welcome-file-list>
        <welcome-file>redirect.jsp</welcome-file>
    </welcome-file-list>
</web-app>
```

Project structure:

I cannot post pictures. But I use standard netbeans structure. HelloworldController.java in in package controller and jsp files are under web-inf/jsp/

Can somebody help m with this problem? I understand the basic interaction but missing xml beans etc.

I am so desperate that I'm thinking of use struts instead of spring. The issue is that I must create web which accessing the database (I think I use hibernate for mapping) and this is my start.

Comment: what you are expecting from community?

Comment: I expect that someone can help me with correct setting of Xml files to make program work.And some additional info so i understand the whole spring basics. And be able to develop my own website. thanks

Comment: the best thing you can do here is to share this project on http://github.com doing so will make helping you so much easier

Comment: I recommend you to read some of tutorials in internet (like this: http://www.mkyong.com/spring-mvc/spring-mvc-hello-world-annotation-example/)

Comment: Check this spring mvc 3.2 hello world complete example in eclipse..
http://www.java4s.com/spring-mvc/spring-mvc-hello-world-spring-mvc-3-2-hello-world-example-in-eclipse/

Answer (score 0):

### With annotations:

## In your dispatcher-servlet.xml:

add these imports:

```
xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
```

Also add them to the list of your schemaLocation:

```
http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.1.xsd
http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc
http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc-3.1.xsd
```

Then you will need to tell the servlet that you want to use annotations, 
Wich can be done by adding:

```
<mvc:annotation-driven/>
```

Next you will need to tell it zhere he should be scanning for controllers:

```
<context:component-scan base-package="ui.controller" />
```

("ui.controller" is what i usually use, feel free to use what ever you like.)

## In your Source Packages folder:

You need to add the location you just defined in your servlet.
So create a new package, for me it will be called "ui.controller".

Then you add a java class to that folder, your Controller.
I'll call it "HelloWorldController".

## In your Controller :

Add the annotation to Ensure the dispatcher knows the class is a Controller.

```
@Controller
public class HelloWorldController{ ... }
```

The next you are willing to do is define when **this** controller is used, since you can use multiple controllers. You can aslo be more specific by defining when a single methode within this controller is used.

To do this you'll use the annotation:

```
@RequestMapping("/HelloWorldPage")
protected ModelAndView showHelloWorldPage(){
    return new ModelAndView("HelloWorldPage")
}
```

So now whener you send a lnk to the location that you defined with the "RequestMapping" annotation the method showHelloWorlPage will be called.

You could even change the requestmapping to something enitrely diffrent like "pageA"

```
@RequestMapping("/PageA")
protected ModelAndView showHelloWorldPage(){
    return new ModelAndView("HelloWorldPage")
}
```

which doesn't exsit and call that page from your view:

```
<a href ="PageA.htm">Hello</a>
```

This wil Ensure that the link shown to your users doesn't tell them the filenames.